# How do I find the first of a few characters in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I find the first of a few characters in a string in python? I have used find() and index() but they find only one character. How do I find the first position of a single character out of the few characters I want to be searched for?

So I want to find the position of the first operator(out of the 4 arithmetic operators) in an inputted string else it should return -1.

Sorry if this is a very stupid question but I have been searching and trying out multiple options over the past few days. I am also a beginner in python.

I tried this but i know its wrong:

```
>>> str1 ='12-23+23*12/12'
>>> str1.find('+') or str1.find('-') or str1.find('*') or str1.find('/')
```

This returns the first operator shown that is the + operator.
Also, I have tried

```
for x in str1:
    if (x=='+' or x=='-' or x=='*' or x=='/'):
        print(str1[x])
```

I know this is wrong.
I am a beginner and I'm trying to learn over a summer course I have taken. So I have not much knowledge on the topic.

Comment: Do you have a code example that shows that you have at least tried to solve it yourself?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Comment: I edited and have shown something I have tried. But it is all wrong.

Comment: the reason your attempt doesn't work is that `find('+')` will continue until it finds a `+`, and if it does, `or` short-circuiting will prevent the other finds from even running.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out. Is there a way to optimize the code and make it work?

Comment: @SheshankPs sure: instead of using `or`, use `min` of your calls to `find`. That will return the lowest index returned by either of the `find`s, which is the index of the first operator.

Comment: @Zinki What does "min" of your calls to "find" mean? Do you mind writing that code if this is wrong: min(str1.find('+') or str1.find('-') or str1.find('*') or str1.find('/'))

Answer (score -1):

```
str1 ='12-23+23*12/12+65'

while(1):
    if('+' not in str2): #Taking '+' as an example
        break;
    int found = str1.find(+)
    print(found)    
    str2 = str1.replace('+','',1)
    #str2 = str1[:found]+str1[found+1:]
```

There is another way to do what I did in the last line of the code. I have added it in the comment above.

```
str2 = str1[:found]+str1[found+1:]
```

Comment: I have no clue how this statement works "str2 = str1[:found]+str1[found+1:]" I dont understand .(I am a real noob)

Comment: What this statement will do is it will remove from str1 the char found at index 'found' and will store the resulting string in str2.

Comment: Are you getting the results using this code? Tell me first if this code is running without errors and giving the right output

Comment: There are a bunch of errors and I am trying to fix it. But the last thing you want me to do is to check your program.

Comment: `>>>while(1):
 str2 = str1.replace('+','',1)
 if('+' not in str2):
  break;
        found = str1.find('+')
        print(found)
        
SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

Comment: Don't copy paste this code directly. Write the same things but using only tabs for indentations.

Comment: I didnt get any satisfactory results. Do you mind checking and telling me.

Answer (score -2):

you can do do something like below:

```
validInput = set(['+','-','*','/'])
checkString = '12-23+23*12*12'

def checkInput(input):
  if input not in validInput:
    raise Exception
  return input

def findSign(sign,string):
  sign = checkInput(sign)
  if sign in string:
    return string.find(sign)
  return -1

print(findSign('/',checkString))
```

Comment: I dont know set, raise, Exception.

Comment: Is there a way to make it more beginner friendly.